# Add more than one custom post type to wordpress home page post loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

i do not know much about coding and I found code online to help me add a custom post type to my wordpress home page but when i tried to use the same code again to add another custom post type the posts won't display. If i only add the first post type, that code will display the first function. As soon as I add another post type after the first one, none of my custom post types will display. I am assuming I need to add something between them? I have tried } but that does not work. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

FIRST FUNCTION

```
function first_function( $query ) {
 if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
 $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'first_function') );
 return $query;
 }
 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'first_function' );
```

SECOND FUNCTION

```
function second_function( $query ) {
 if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
 $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'second_function') );
 return $query;
 }
 add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'second_function' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function overwrites the query of the first. It's not necessary anyway as you can add as many post types to the $query->set line in the first function as you need, like this:

`$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'first_function', 'my-second-post-type','another-post-type' ) );`

BTW, is your post type actually called 'first_function'? Just asking as that's the name of the function too.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this method and see what I get. No it's not called first_function. I think I was trying to be as descriptive as I could but being a newbie, it didn't go over too well. lol. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. If it works for you, don't forget to come back and mark the answer as accepted :-) BTW - always best to be as accurate as possible if posting code - don't change it as you might just change the bit that's causing the problem

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the advice and thanks again for your quick solution. Have a wonderful weekend!

Comment: You're welcome. One last bit of advice - change the line `if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )` to `if ( !is_admin() && is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )` - you're already testing for the home page, so it shouldn't be necessary, but by including `!is_admin()` you're making sure that it won't ever be run on the admin side of your site (ie, the "Dashboard")... belt & braces really!

Comment: Awesome! I changed to what you suggested and it seems to be working fine. Thanks again for your help! :)